# camera view of Viewport render image is different from rendered image

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, video-sequence-editor

I want to set camera at various locations in a scene and render images.  In one scene that I am working on now, the camera view as seen from viewport is different from the camera view that is in the rendered image.
Ive googled extensively and tried the following solutions:

1. checking the " lock to camera view' option
2. unchecking 'sequencer' in postprocessing
3. delete all key frames and re do.  I also additionally deleted the existing camera and added a new one, set its properties again.  But of no avail

There are no hidden cameras in the scene also.  How can I rectify this?

Comment: Could you share some screenshots to show how it is different? Did you add scene strips to the sequencer in a new scene and in the sidebar select the camera?

Comment: No, I did not do any of that.  The blend that I am talking about was downloaded from blender.org's free demo file.  https://www.blender.org/download/demo-files/  'Architectural Visualization".  To reproduce the error, try downloading the blend file and set a random, relevant camera position and try to render the view.  The rendered image focuses on a washing machine, while you could have set the camera to view the dining table in the scene